# Are both sentences correct?

Tags: grammar

1) If I had found a good house , I would have bought one.
2) I would have bought a house if I had found a good one.

Answer (score 3):

They are different ways of saying the same thing. Both are correct and idiomatic.

Answer (score -1):

Change the 1st sentence to, "If I had found a good house, I would have bought it."

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! Please explain why your answer is correct; answers without explanation don't teach the patterns of English well and [may be deleted](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3294/18673).